# Android Rxjava and Retrofit in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit, observer-pattern

I am using Kotlin for the Android and I have implemented MVP Architecture along with Retrofit for Network call and Rxjava,dagger implementation.
However today the problem is that I am trying to fetch following json response using post service. The json is like below that I need to retrieve with given following parameters

{
    "success": {
        "id": 32,
        "otp": 3413,
        "msg": "Otp has sent on this number"
    }
}

so I have used something like this for the coding

```
override fun login(api_token: String, name: String, mobile: String, lat: String, lon: String, address: String) {
        var subscribe = api.login(api_token,mobile.toInt(),lat.toDouble(),lon.toDouble(),address).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ list: LoginParentResponseModel? ->
                    Log.i("login",list!!.toString())
                    view.showProgress(false)
                    view.loadLoginSuccess(list!!.success)
                }, { error ->
                    view.loadLoginFailure("loginfailed")
                    view.showProgress(false)
                    view.showErrorMessage("error"+error.toString())

                })
        subscriptions.add(subscribe)

    }
```

This below is login response model

```
data class LoginParentResponseModel(val success : Map<String,String>,val error : Map<String,String>)
```

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: problem is that i am getting 401 error .. i guess the response is not being wrapped in json

Comment: The 401 Unauthorized error is an HTTP status code that means the page you were trying to access cannot be loaded until you first log in with a valid user ID and password.

Comment: 401 error means that your request are not authorized. At first I think you need to authenticate with the server.

Comment: i am authenticating it with the server

Comment: it executes the error part block from the above code

Comment: You are trying to login since you are calling api.login and you are sending api_token along? Also you state in the paragraph, that you are trying to fetch response, but using post method? Please clarify your intentions.

Comment: yes i am sending api_token along for the login . yes i am trying to fetch response and the response is in the json as posted above with the question . thanks @Kubicko

Comment: I think you should put api_token in your request header